# chrome não depura com netbeans conecttor

Tags: netbeans, plugin

Instalei a extensão (*plugin*) *Netbeans conector* para o navegador Chrome porém não abre nada, somente uma tela branca com a mensagem "netbeans conecttor" esta fazendo a depuração desta guia.
Alguém já passou por isso? Tem uma solução?

Comment: Estranho porque eu a utilizava e não precisei fazer nada extra, somente instalar o *plugin* mesmo. O Netbeans, por padrão, vai executar uma página chamada `index.html` (na raiz do diretório web) e se não existir um arquivo com esse nome ele abrirá uma página em branco, não será isso? Se você excluiu o arquivo mencionado antes e criou outros arquivos html/jsp, eu até posso dar uma resposta.

Comment: tem o arquivo index.xhtml na raiz da pasta "paginas web" é um projeto jsf que fiz na faculdade. acredito que tudo esta correto pois foi todo desenvolvido pelo professor, somente no meu not esta com o este problema no lab da faculdade abre normal... sera que tenho que configurar algo na ide?

Comment: No arquivo `web.xml` tem alguma tag `<welcome-file>`?

Comment: seria esta? 
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

Comment: Hum, ja foi definido o arquivo de boas vindas. Se o projeto ta ok, não seria o servidor? Ta usando o tomcat?

Comment: Sim estou usando o tomcat na porta 8084.
segue print do log: http://prntscr.com/7ebyr6

Comment: Então o problema não é o *plugin* e sim algo na sua aplicação que está lançando uma `NullPointerException`. Dá uma olhada no método `doFilter` na classe `FiltroBD`, sem o código não tem como dar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Comigo também aconteceu quando estava tentando subir um "index.php".

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

na barra de ferramentas do NETBEANS abra os navegadores que podem ser usados escolha: **"Chrome Browser Default do IDE"**.

O meu não funcionava pois estava marcado somente Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Aconteceu o mesmo problema comigo, resolvi da seguinte maneira:

> Abra a opção Ferramentas => Opções => Web Browser selecione Chrome => Clique em Ok.

Ao lado esquerdo do ícone executar projeto, existe um ícone de navegador, selecione "Browser default do IDE", ícone relacionado ao navegador selecionado anteriormente.