# Netbeans Connector e Chrome - MAC OS

Tags: netbeans, google-chrome, osx

Recentemente migrei minha IDE de desenvolvimento, NetBeans, do Linux para MAC OS.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo depurar meu projeto Java EE no Chrome utilizando a extensão NetBeans Connector.

Simplesmente, ao solicitar a depuração, no Chrome abre somente uma página em branco com a URL `file:///private/var/folders/xc/2h230k1j75q4s7hk1mymy40r0000gp/T/blank6473583437075718674.html` e nada mais acontece.

Se eu acessar através do endereço `localhost:8080/NomeDoProjeto`, a aplicação funciona normalmente, porém não consigo depurar nesta condição.

No LOG do NetBeans não apresenta nenhum erro e no Chrome, ao abrir a Ferramenta do Desenvolvedor, aparece no console somente `<html :netbeans_temporary="true"></html>`

A versão do NetBeans é a 8.2, a versão do Chrome é a 63.0.3239.84 (Versão oficial) 64 bits e a versão do NetBeans Connector é a 1.1.5.

Comment: Somente reforçando, ja pesquisei sobre isto e averiguei as soluções deste post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67492/chrome-n%C3%A3o-depura-com-netbeans-conecttor?rq=1.  Nada resolveu.